# How to use a loop with datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have two different time and I want to start whit first time and step forward with a specific number to reach second time how can I implement that with python
Example:
10:00:00
10:15:00
10:30:00
10:45:00
11:00:00

Comment: What type are you start and end time variables?

Comment: I don't know if there's another way but you can easily convert it to seconds then add the number you want then convert it back to datetime

Comment: @Mureinik integer for Example: time2=datetime.timedelta(hours=10,minutes=30)
time3=datetime.timedelta(hours=11,minutes=10) |

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python makes this fairly straightforward if you use its standard datetime library:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start = datetime(2020, 1, 1, 10, 0)
end = datetime(2020, 1, 1, 11, 0)

timestamp = start
while timestamp <= end:
    print(timestamp.time())
    timestamp += timedelta(minutes=15)
```

Result:

```
10:00:00
10:15:00
10:30:00
10:45:00
11:00:00
```

Note that you don't really need the date, but using `datetime` over `time` (which wouldn't include the date) makes the rest of the code easier to write and understand. You could of course implement a subclass of `time` that works well with `timedelta` - but that's more advanced and well beyond the question.

The date I picked (2020-01-01) is arbitrary, it will work with any recent date. You could use `today` with `combine` and `time` for example.